# jquery .prop(checked,true) value not reflected in method invoked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

```
  $('#toggleBtn'+stepCount).on('click', function () {
                        $('.toggleswitch-checkbox').each(function () {
                            if (this.id === btnId) {
                                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                                    alert("checked true");
                                    $(this).prop('checked', false).change();

                                } else {
                                    alert("checked false");
                                    $(this).prop('checked', true).change();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

the toggle btn is as below, but am rendering it dynamically as below

```
<td><div class="toggleswitch"><input class="toggleswitch-checkbox" id="toggleBtn' + stepCount + '" checked data-height="35" data-off="Issue" data-offstyle="danger" data-on="Success" data-onstyle="success" data-style="android" \n\
                                        data-toggle="toggle" data-width="100" type="checkbox"  onchange=renderDivs("toggleBtn' + stepCount + '")><label class="toggleswitch-label" for="preCheckToggleBtn' + stepCount
                            + '"><span class="toggleswitch-inner"></span><span class="toggleswitch-switch"></span></label></div></td>
```

For the strangest reason, once the prop checked, true runs, the renderDivs function isnt receiving value true for the prop but always getting false.

Please help

Kind of trying to get the prop checked printed in renderDivs, not sure why it is not alerting

https://jsfiddle.net/ceju8kgd/5/

Comment: Can you show a full working example of the HTML and JS. There seems to be lots of things which could be potential issues here, but it's hard to diagnose with any accuracy without seeing it working.

Comment: You'll need to create an [mcve] version that *demonstrates* the problem.  https://jsfiddle.net/m9wvh7er/ Here's a fiddle that shows that using prop(checked,false) works fine.  Perhaps it's your check against `btnId` or the fact that you're using the click event of a checkbox to change its state (while the click event *already* changes the state).

Comment: Trying adding `return false` to the end of your click event so the browser doesn't change/re-change the checked status.

Comment: trying to create a fiddle for this, will update soon

Comment: @freedomn-m are you implying I do not need to write an on.click function

Comment: Depends on what you want to do.  Given the code you've got is: checkbox.click = change checkbox value.  Then no, you don't need *any* code for that, that's what checkboxes do.   If you want to know when one changes (for your alert) then one event handler will suffice: `$(document).on("change", ".toggleswitch-checkbox", function() { alert($(this).is(":checked")) });`

Comment: Not really sure what your fiddle is trying to do, but "onclick=" won't work unless you change the "onload" option.  Updated the fiddle (including the typo within renderDivs): https://jsfiddle.net/7quem95L/

Comment: Always look in the console for errors - fiddle was giving `renderDivs is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Check if checkbox is checked with this method:

```
$(this).is(":checked")
```

Comment: The checked part works fine, the back toggle is what is not working..  if ($(this).prop('checked')) does alert checked true, the false path also alerts checked false but the renderDivs function gets false always, 2nd case it should receive checked as true as I have back toggled. so basically the change isnt being propagated to the js function

Comment: $(this).prop('checked', false).trigger('change'); or trigger('click')

Comment: the change gets triggered however it isnt receiving the correct prop value, its getting passed false as always